# how to make command run in specific server in discord.py 2.0

Tags: python, discord.py

Im a noob python developer with discord.py 2.0.
I want to make a command that only runs in specific servers.
This is my original code below.

I want to make this command to run in only specific server.
I googled a lot but I cant find the perfect solution for this.
So how can I make this to run in only specific server?

I tried @app_commands.guild() but it didn't worked.
There were such a ctx commands in google so I can't find the right one.

````py
@app_commands.command(description='Shows the update log')
async def UPDlogs(self, interaction: Interaction) -> None:
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFFFFFF)
    embed.set_author(name='~~~ Bot update log')
    embed.add_field(
        name='v.1.6.1 update',
        value=f"1. bla bla bla\n"
        "2. some update logs\n"
        "3. how to solve this?\n",
        inline=False,
    )
    view = ui.View()
    view.add_item(ui.Button(label='Discord', emoji="", url="https://discord.com", row=0))
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view, ephemeral=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You may use discord.py 2.0 to make a command run only in specified servers by checking the server's ID before executing the command. If the server ID matches one of the permissible IDs, the command can be executed; otherwise, an error message stating that the command is not permitted in that server can be displayed.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

# Define your allowed server IDs
allowed_server_id = [1234567890, 9876543210]  # Replace these with your server IDs

# Create your bot instance
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='YOUR_PREFIX_HERE', description='Your bot description')

@bot.command(description='Shows the update log')
async def UPDlogs(ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    # Check if the command is being used in an allowed server
    if ctx.guild.id in allowed_server_ids:
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFFFFFF)
        embed.set_author(name='~~~ Bot update log')
        embed.add_field(
            name='v.1.6.1 update',
            value=f"1. bla bla bla\n"
            "2. some update logs\n"
            "3. how to solve this?\n",
            inline=False,
        )
        view = ui.View()
        view.add_item(ui.Button(label='Discord', emoji="", url="https://discord.com", row=0))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
    else:
        await ctx.send("This command is not allowed in this server.")

# Run bot
bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE')
```